# concatenation of Landsat images Side by side

Tags: image, gis, google-earth-engine, landsat, libgee

My interest area is consisting of two path and single row(WRS2 path-138, row-45), I want to concatenate two scenes from two path and clip the desired area according to given geometric polygon and saved the clipped image on google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ".filterBounds()" function, ".mosaic()" reduction, and ".clip()" is a possible shortcut.

The ".filterBounds()" function pretends to filter only for images with "touch" de Region of Interest - ROI, the ".mosaic()" will reduce the entire pile of images  (attention to the stack based structure) to only one ee.Image object, for clipping use the function ".clip" over an ee.Image.

Check the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/59a6e7e175307a164094a3335574f7b4